# Even the first line of .net core controller is not executed

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I am totally lost here, I don't even know how to debug this thing.

So I have created a controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<GlistaUserDTO>> GetGlistaUserAsync(int id)
{
    var glistaUserBLModel = await _userBL.GetGlistaUserAsync(id); // <--- breakpoint here
    var glistaUserDTO = _mapper.Map<GlistaUserDTO>(glistaUserBLModel);

    return glistaUserDTO;
}
```

and I am using swagger to test it. The input is some random integer and a breakpoint on the first line in controller should pause the execution. However, it doesn't even get to the breakpoint.  The swagger pages blinks (I guess it refreshes or whatever) and that is it. I get no server response.

I have other (not GET but POST) controller that works just fine.

Since it does execution obviously does not even reach the controller, what are other ways to debug this?

[image]

Comment: you require authentication. That's what 401 means

Comment: @RichardHubley You are correct. `[AllowAnnonymous]` solved everything. Lifesaver! If you are willing to post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP Status Code 401 means Authentication is required. And is the reason you aren't getting to any line of code.

Suppling the proper Bearer token, or using the attribute [AllowAnnonymous] should allow you to reach your break point.